# Why double does not return correct precision?

Tags: java, double

Below program returns `0.009999999999999998`. My question is why it does not return `.01`.

```
    double a = 0.02;
    double b = 0.03;
    double c = b - a;
    System.out.println(c);
```

I know `BigDecimal` will return expected output but i want to understand By what logic  answer is `0.009999999999999998` in double ?

Comment: The closest representable value for 0.03 is slightly lower than 0.03 and the closest representable value for 0.02 is slightly higher (you can use BigDecimal to prove this) when you take the difference you get a value which is slightly lower than 0.01. The simplest way to deal with this is to use rounding of the answer `System.out.printf("%.2f%n", c);`